# Boolean to text mapping in Grafana

Tags: grafana

I have **a single stat** view that displays `true` or `false` based on the last value correctly from the data.  However, I wish to map this to the text as follows:

- `false` -> `Radiator Off`
- `true`  -> `Radiator On`

I've tried the values `0`,  `0.0`, `true` and `false` in the value mappings and nothing seems to change what is on screen.  If I have *a null mapping* and do something such as *average the values* this *correctly displays the text*.  I've also listed my data in a table view and this shows `0.0` and `1.0` for the `true/false` states.

Does ***Grafana*** text mapping work with ***boolean values***?  There is nothing in the help that mentions anything about booleans.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think because we're using **Grafana** to visualize *time series data*, therefore **values** should only in ***numeric*** or ***null***.

Grafana don't have **text mapping**, I think you're referring **Value Mappings**.

You can convert **boolean** values from your query to **numeric**, such as `true` to `1` and `false` to `0`, Value Mappings will work.

I've tried on https://play.grafana.org/ for mapping from `0` to `Off` and `1` to `On`, it worked well :D

Thanks for reading !!

[image]